# ActiveRecord - Finding all objects with shared attributes in a join model

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have three models

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :captain
  has_many    :boat_classifications
  has_many    :classifications, through: :boat_classifications
end

class Classification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boat_classifications
  has_many :boats, through: :boat_classifications
end

class BoatClassification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boat
  belongs_to :classification
end
```

I'm trying to write a simple ActiveRecord query to find all the boats of type sailboat. Something like `Boat.where(classifications: "Sailboat")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
Boat.joins(:classifications).where(classifications: { name: 'Sailboat' }) # name or whatever field contains Sailboat
```

Generates this query:

```
SELECT `boats`.* FROM `boats` INNER JOIN `boat_classifications` ON `boat_classifications`.`boat_id` = `boats`.`id` INNER JOIN `classifications` ON `classifications`.`id` = `boat_classifications`.`classification_id` WHERE `classification`.`name` = 'Sailboat'
```

Comment: I was soooo close! Thanks. Awesome answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
Boat.includes(:classifications).where(classifications: {id: Classification.sailboats})
```

For this to work, you also need a scope on `Classification` like this:

```
def self.sailboats
  where(name: "Sailboat")
end
```